# opencart - product option still showing even though it is disabled in back end

Tags: opencart

I've not really used OpenCart before so not entirely sure if what I'm doing is correct or not.

I'm using OpenCart 1.5.6.4 and implementing OpenStock in order for me to add several options and prices for products.

To clarify, I have an ethernet cable in the store, but it is available in different lengths and colours. However, in my admin area under Option Stock tab in Products, I have disabled the 0.5m Green cable - yet it is still shown on the front end, and can even be added to the cart. Checking the database, it is definitely set to 0 in the active column, so why is it still showing? Or am I missing something really obvious?

If my question seems too vague, please tell me - I can explain more if need be.

Thank you,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Clear OpenCart cache:

1. Locate cache folder under system/storage/cache
2. Open cache folder and select all files
3. Delete files

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I think because there are two levels of options, it needs to be dependent on the first chosen one. So, a 0.3m Grey cable is inactive but a 0.3m red cable IS active - and similarly  a 1m grey cable IS active but a 1m red cable is INactive. It's a bit complicated, but since the options pre-load, I don't think it's an easy task..

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the modifications cache in the admin.  I found that to be very useful when most things dont update on the public side.